# SMS/MMS data location on Android, Cordova/PhoneGap, Cordova-Plugin-File

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I'm creating a Cordova app and I'm using their file plugin to access files within the system. the problem is, it doesn't seem to recognize the file.

One thing I know is different android versions have different locations for messages, according to [source](https://www.tenorshare.com/android-recovery/where-are-text-messages-stored-on-android.html), my emulator which that runs Android version 13 should have the messages located here: **/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db**.
According to [source1](https://thesecmaster.com/explore-the-android-file-system-hierarchy-in-depth/) **/data** is one of the root folders on the android system.

Assume this code is within on device ready:

```
    function success(fileEntry)
    {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                var content = this.result;
                alert(content);
        };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }

    function fail(e)
    {
        alert('failed to locate file: ',e);
    }
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db',success, fail);
```

When emulating, it runs the fail callback function.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong? I'm not well read on Cordova and the help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can't have access to that directory.
[Read the documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#where-to-store-files) to know which folders you have access to and resolve the path.

Comment: what if the device is rooted